# Get scroll position with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, scroll, next.js

I want to know if the user has scrolled or not to update the UI in NextJS. I have the following code, all the examples I have found have the same code:

```js
  const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState(0);

  const onScroll = (event) => {
    const { pageYOffset, scrollY } = window;
    console.log("yOffset", pageYOffset, "scrollY", scrollY);
    setScrollY(window.pageYOffset);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll, { passive: true });
    // remove event on unmount to prevent a memory leak
    () => document.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll, { passive: true });
  }, []);
```

But the scroll does not get updated, neither with `document` nor `window`. I always get the same output:

[image]

Any suggestion?
Thanks:)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`onScroll` function destroyed and created again on every re-render when states changes so its object id change too.
and the one defined on useEffect shouldn't be changed.

You need to use useCallback to prevent this behavior and wrap `onScroll` in it.

and also **addEventListener** to the `window`, because you are reading *pageYOffset, scrollY* from `window` on the **onScroll** function

```
  const onScroll = useCallback(event => {
      const { pageYOffset, scrollY } = window;
      console.log("yOffset", pageYOffset, "scrollY", scrollY);
      setScrollY(window.pageYOffset);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    //add eventlistener to window
    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll, { passive: true });
    // remove event on unmount to prevent a memory leak with the cleanup
    return () => {
       window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll, { passive: true });
    }
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [isFixed, setIsFixed] = useState(false);
  const scrollThreshold = 200;

  useEffect(() => {
     const handleScroll = () => {
      setIsFixed(document.body.scrollTop >= scrollThreshold);
     };

    document.body.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      document.body.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);
```

Render class:

```
<header className={`text-lg ${isFixed ? 'fixed' : ''}`}>
```

Customize *fixed* class. I prefer `position:sticky`

Source: [Next.js repo](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18299)

Answer (score -1):

Use This it will work :)

````
const handleScroll = () => {
  setClientWindowHeight(window.scrollY);
};

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll); 
  return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);```
});
````

Comment: In Next 14 when I use addEventListener from the window it does not even trigger. the only way to trigger is to use a document.body.addEventListener, but in that case window.scrollY always shows me 0.