window.scrollY always remains 0 in next.js
I'm building in next.js.
I want to get window.scrollY position on onScroll event of InfiniteScroll.
but issue is, window.scrollY & X always remains 0.
ths is how I'm trying:
  const onScroll = (e) => {
    console.log(window)
    console.log(window.scrollY)
  }

 <InfiniteScroll
          dataLength={articles?.length || 0}
          next={() => {
            fetchMore({
              variables: {
                offset: articles?.length || 0,
              },
            });
          }}
          hasMore={articles?.length < articlesCount}
          loader={<></>}
          scrollableTarget="scrollableDiv"
          onScroll={onScroll}
          // initialScrollY={5000}
        >

I also tried on :
 <Styled.PageContainer id="scrollableDiv"  onScroll={onScroll}>

but still it remains 0.
output:

is there anything needs to be done in specailly next.js?

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70659833/1427878

Nope. Event listner does not even trigger. I use next: ^13.3.0

Are you actually scrolling the root element, or is it perhaps some container deeper down, with a fixed height and overflow set to scroll/auto?
